# How can I run Jest test in band with the VSCode extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I want to run the Jest tests in band, because otherwise they will cause errors.

But I have no clue how to solve that problem. It works everything fine when I run the tests with the command line.

Answer (score 5):

In VSCode settings, change the `Jest: Path to Jest` to the command line you're running.
For example:

```
npm test -- --runInBand
```

[image: screenshot of vscode setting]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it right now and everything works as expected

Comment: What are the two strokes `--` before the arg? In Git, two strokes have a meaning - only filenames after these-, in Vscode/package.json sure as well

Comment: In shell, double-hyphen `--` signifies the end of the parameter/option list.  In this case, we are telling it that the things that follow are not parameters to `npm`.  Instead this is passed on to the command that `npm` runs, in this case, `jest` gets the parameter `--runInBand`.

Answer (score 3):

In new version of vscode `jest.pathToJest` is deprecated, instead you should set `jest.jestCommandLine`.
You can either use the settings panel to set the value for the `jestCommandLine`. like this:
[image]

Or you can manually update the `settings.json` like this:

```json
"jest.jestCommandLine": "\"./node_modules/.bin/jest\" --runInBand"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is

```
"jest.jestCommandLine": "npx jest"
```